# NotifyDataSetChanged cannot access in arrayadapter

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, notifydatasetchanged

I have a list which can be updated by user but there was an error on `notifyDataSetChanged()` I'm doing a to-do list, when I added `notifyDataSetChanged()` in array adapter it shows an error said that

> error: notifyDataSetChanged() in ArrayAdapter is defined in an inaccessible class or interface
>
> Cannot access 'notifyDataSetChanged()' in 'android.widget.ArrayAdapter'

Error happened on **note_editor**.
Following is my code:

**note_editor** (another activity)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_note_editor);

        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);


        Intent intent = getIntent();
        noteId = intent.getIntExtra("noteId", -1);
        // note id variable transferred from main activity

        if (noteId != -1) { 

            editText.setText(MainActivity.notes.get(noteId));

        } else {

            MainActivity.notes.add("");
            noteId = MainActivity.notes.size() - 1; 
            MainActivity.arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  //error happened here       
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
                getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences
                        ("com.example.application1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


        HashSet<String> set = (HashSet<String>)
                sharedPreferences.getStringSet("notes", null);

        if (set == null) {

            notes.add("Example note");

        } else {

            notes = new ArrayList(set);

        }


        arrayAdapter = new CustomAdapter
                (this, R.layout.simplerow, notes);

        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new 
 Intent(getApplicationContext(),note_editor.class); 

                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick
            (AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        note_editor.class);
                intent.putExtra("noteId", i);
                startActivity(intent);

            }

        });



listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

 public boolean onItemLongClick
   (AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
          final int itemToDelete = i;
                 new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                         .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                         .setTitle("Are you sure?")
                         .setMessage("Do you want to delete this note?")
                         .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        notes.remove(itemToDelete);

            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("com.example.application1",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

HashSet<String> set = new HashSet(MainActivity.notes);
sharedPreferences.edit().putStringSet("notes", set).apply();

                        }
                   }
              )

             .setNegativeButton("No", null)
             .show();


                        return true;
                    }


                });

    }
```

**CustomAdapter**

```
private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        Context context;
        ArrayList<String> notes = new ArrayList<>();
        int layoutResourceId;
        public CustomAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
                            ArrayList<String> objects) {
            super(context, layoutResourceId, objects);
            this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
            this.notes=objects;
            this.context=context;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        CheckBox chBox = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simplerow,
                        parent, false);
                chBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
                convertView.setTag(chBox);
                chBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
   TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.rowTextView);
   tv.setPaintFlags(tv.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                });
            }
            return convertView;
        }

    }
```

Any ideas what is wrong here?

Comment: Why should you update an adapter of another Activity??

Comment: Because I was planning to do something like when I click on the floating action button it will redirect me to a new page which allows me to write text. Is this the incorrect way to do so?

Comment: Just update the data. When the activity with the listView will be used just read the data and set the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Need to change only one line. Just change arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() as below.

```
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
   TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.rowTextView);
   tv.setPaintFlags(tv.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                });
            }
            return convertView;
        }

    }
```

Comment: but the error is on ```MainActivity.arrayadapter.notifyDataSetChanged()``` in **note_editor**

Comment: add the declaration part of MainActivity. Where you have declared arrayAdapter.

Comment: I think it should be public static CustomAdapter arrayAdapter;

Comment: @Rajnishsuryavanshi It is wrong. There is no reason to update ad adapter used in another Activity. Also no reason to make it static.

Answer (score 0):

Error showing that the adapter object is not accessible.

You are actualy trying to update an activity already destroyed. Notify adapter from MainActivity itself.

Comment: It will be asked to make it static eventually

Comment: yea sorry didn't mention earlier.

Comment: That may be causing the error. MainActivity is already destroyed and your updating. You are actualy trying to update an activity already destroyed.

Comment: So I should remove the ```notifyDataSetChanged``` in the another activity to remove that error?

Comment: Yup, you cannot call notifyDataSetChanged from another activity.

Comment: But if I remove it, the text that I written would not be saved isn't it?

Comment: You will have to save it anywhere like shared preference or sqlite. Else pass that to MainActivity through intent and add to the list.

Comment: So for example I have ```sharedPreferences.edit().putStringSet("notes", set).apply();``` in another activity, if I want to save the text I should create a method that has ```sharedPreferences.getString("notes",null);``` in main activity? Sorry still new to android might need further explanation.

Comment: Are you using note_editor activity only for the purpose of getting values, why should you think about a dialog instead of an activity?

Comment: Technically yes? note_editor activity is to update the arraylist using ```editText```.

Comment: it is better for use a dialog or `Fragment` instead of activity, value return from frament/ dialog can be used to update the list.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the error happens because you defined your CustomAdapter as a **private** class, and for that reason you cannot access its methods outside of it.

The CustomAdapter should be defined as **public** (or package access if everything is located on the same package).

That being said, I agree with other comments pointing out that that's not the proper way to call **notifyDataSetChanged** (if you still have doubts about it, I suggest opening a different question for that).

Comment: Indeed, the error has gone but there's another problem shown up, the ```editText``` cannot be saved.